# Export Hive data to files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, sqoop, avro

What's the best way to export Hive data to files so that they can be used by Sqoop export later? I have some hive tables but I want to join them and export them to files in such a way I can use Sqoop to export them to a different system.

I can use something like that:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY $fileLocation
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
SELECT * from ...... INNER JOIN......
```

So my questions are, is the any better way to do that? How much Avro can speed up this process? Since I need to use Sqoop later, TEXT & AVRO are only my options, right?

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set avro.output.codec=snappy;

INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY $fileLocation
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS AVRO
SELECT * FROM ..... INNER JOIN......
```

It will definitely compress the file but Sqoop will need to decompress it before export. So is that still a better option? Any other options I should try here?

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop can export Hive data directly from the HDFS directory that underlies the Hive table by using the `--export-dir` Sqoop export parameter.

You can find the HDFS directory that maps to the Hive table by running this command in Hive:

```
hive> DESCRIBE EXTENDED tablename;
...
...location:hdfs://path/to/the/table/data...
...
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for your response. I know that but in this case I didn't want to create a table.

Comment: Ok, I think I was confused by your mention of the keyword `LOCAL`. You will need to create a table to do this, but if it's an `EXTERNAL` table then you can drop the table immediately after populating it and the data will stay on HDFS but the table definition will no longer exist.

Comment: You are right, "LOCAL" was typo, I wanted to change it after I put this question but didn't find a way. As I need to use Sqoop, so definitely it can't be LOCAL filesystem.

Back to my question, assume I have a table and this table might be use as storing delta data. After exporting it, it will be truncated. So is there any other way to achieve this? I'm trying to find a faster way. How much fileformat will help here to improve the performance? Another way is pipe the Hive output (from script) and then compress it and use something else (not Sqoop) to move the data.

Comment: Using Sqoop is the standard and typically fastest way to do this, because it can operate in parallel. AFAIK Sqoop currently can only export delimited text files so other formats such as Avro would not be compatible.

Comment: You sure? Though I have used text files most of the times with Sqoop but I encountered this: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/SQOOP-227

Comment: Ok, good to know! The documentation doesn't mention it so I assumed it wasn't implemented.